# Accessing YouTube Data APi v2

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

When choosing APIs to access in the "Services" tab of the Google APIs Console, the only YouTube APIs listed are "YouTube Data API v3" and "YouTube Analytics API".

**Does accessing the data api v3 allow me access to v2 as well?** I need to use the comment functionality since I don't believe it's in v3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For v2 of the data API, you'll still need to create a client ID/secret in the API console to do oAuth2 authentication, but when it comes to simple data calls, rather than getting an API key from that same console you will instead have to register your app and get an older developer key from the YouTube dashboard; you can do so here:

https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard

(also, you are correct that comments are not yet part of the v3 data API, so using v2 is the supported method to interact with that info).